# How to create customs views dynamically?

Tags: android, view

I'm trying to find a way to create a custom views dynamically, but I didn't find a useful post for my problem.

I have the next view.

[image: View]

And this is the tree of the layout:

[image: Layouts]

I want to create as many copies as items received, but I need to change the textviews inside per each item.

I don't know If I have explained me well. Thank you.

EDIT:

I follow some of your advises, and I make this:

```
private void addInputHeader(int timestamp)
    {
        LinearLayout mRootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.event_container);
        View mChildView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.program_event_day_header, mRootLayout, false);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mRootLayout.addView(mChildView, params);

        TextView tv_day = (TextView) mChildView.findViewById(R.id.tv_day);

        tv_day.setText(getDayForHeader(timestamp) + getResources().getString(R.string.of) + getMonthForHeader(timestamp));

    }

    private void addInputDescription(int timestamp, String description)
    {
        LinearLayout mRootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.event_container);
        View mChildView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.program_event_day_header, mRootLayout, false);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mRootLayout.addView(mChildView, params);

        TextView tv_event_hour = (TextView) mChildView.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_hour);
        TextView tv_event_message = (TextView) mChildView.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_message);

        tv_event_hour.setText(getHour(timestamp) + " - ");
        tv_event_message.setText(description);
    }

    private String getDayForHeader(long timeStamp){
        Date df = new Date(timeStamp*1000);
        return new SimpleDateFormat("cccc dd").format(df);
    }

    private String getMonthForHeader(long timeStamp){
        Date df = new Date(timeStamp*1000);
        return new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(df);
    }

    private String getHour(long timeStamp){
        Date df = new Date(timeStamp*1000);
        return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(df);
    }

    private int getD(long timeStamp){
        Date df = new Date(timeStamp*1000);
        return Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(df));
    }

    private int getM(long timeStamp){
        Date df = new Date(timeStamp*1000);
        return Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(df));
    }

    private int getY(long timeStamp){
        Date df = new Date(timeStamp*1000);
        return Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(df));
    }
```

But I'm getting a NullPointerException when the addInputDescription tries to set text on tv_event_hour.

Comment: Do you want to create list kind of layout ?

Comment: Yes, like a list, but with the layout contained in the ScrollView of the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Add row view layout that represent ui row.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RightTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right Top" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Left Bottom" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RightBottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Right Bottom" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

// Add view as row with msg

```
        private void addMsg() {
                    View msgView = getViewWithMsg("TopLeft", "TopRight", "LeftBottom", "Right Bottom");

                    // msgView represent one row
                    // You can add it to linearlayout desendent to scrollview

                     }
```

// This method create one msg row layout and update msg

```
         private View getViewWithMsg(String TopLeft, String TopRight, String LeftBottom,
        String RightBottom) {
         LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)  getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         View root = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

         TextView topLeft = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.leftTop);
         TextView topRight = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.RightTop);
         TextView bottomLeft = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.leftBottom);
         TextView botomRight = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.RightBottom);

         topLeft.setText(TopLeft);
         topRight.setText(TopRight);
         bottomLeft.setText(LeftBottom);
         botomRight.setText(RightBottom);

     return root;

}
```

Comment: Getting viewmsg you can add it to lauout container. If u are using listview then use addapter that instantiats the row and update values.

Answer (score 1):

Create an VO for your items and add it in to the layout.
Like, layout.add(item)

Answer (score 1):

See the following code if you're trying to add a child view (or multiple) to your root `LinearLayout`:

```
    LinearLayout mRootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_root);
    View mChildView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ll_child, mRootLayout,
            false);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mRootLayout.addView(mChildView, params);
    TextView tvEventHour = (TextView) mChildView.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_hour);
    TextView tvEventMessage = (TextView) mChildView.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_message);

    tvEventHour.setText("10:30");
    tvEventMessage.setText("Fugia corum...");
```

**Note:** If the list is about to get very long you should consider using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) with an Adapter since this is alot better performance-wise.

Comment: I have done some methods like your solution, I have posted it in my first post. I'm getting a NullPointerException, but I don't know why?

Comment: That's because both methods (`addInputDescription(...)` and `addInputHeader(...)`) inflate `R.layout.program_event_day_header` while the layout should be something different for the description

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate from xml:

```
View placeHolderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_header_placeholder, mListView);
```

What do you mean by "change the textviews inside per each item."? 
If you need the textview inside the inflated layout try this:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)placeHolderView.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
```